# What's the difference between hamshachah and hashpa'ah?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

Within the contexts of learning Chassidus what is the difference between hamshachah and hashpa'ah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamshachah is when the person draws down G-dliness by his or her own efforts in avodas Hashem.

Hashpa'ah is what Hashem pours down upon the person in the form of spiritual or physical blessing and guidance. (This is without referring to what, if anything, merited the Hashpa'ah.)